# How do I fix the three.js "url.lastIndexOf is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'm currently working on loading a gLTF in Three.js r105. After loading the file I tried to change the url after loading it to see if I could some how change it after loading it. This is were my problem started.

First I just tried changing the url inside the "onLoad". Then I tried changing it in my gltf.scene.traverse. That didn't work either so
then I to turn the input a function as the url parameter.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().load( function () {
window.setTimeout(`this = 'gmtk.glb', alert('It changed');`, 5000);
    **return "sword_1.glb";**
},
```

I expected my gLTF to atleast appear but my entire scene was just black. In the console I had 1 error that said:

```
three.js:38135 Uncaught TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function
    at Object.extractUrlBase (three.js:38135)
    at GLTFLoader.load (GLTFLoader.js:40)
    at Kube.js:31
```

Comment: It seems you are not passing an URL into `GLTFLoader.load()`. The first parameter must be an URL, the second one is the `onLoad()` callback.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to get the function in the url to return the name of my file. I check the error more closely and the problem is here:
```
extractUrlBase: function ( url ) {

   var index = url.lastIndexOf( '/' );

   if ( index === - 1 ) return './';

   return url.substr( 0, index + 1 );

  }
```
Three.js isn't calling the function because it expects a value.

Comment: That's right. `url` has to be a string. You can't pass in a function.

Comment: Yes that is true but you can get around that by making the function return the url: ... function g () { return 'sword_1.glb' };

 var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().load( g() ...

Comment: My gltf is loading properly, now I just need a way to change it's url. (and in turn its geometry and material)

Comment: Is there any way to turn on object3d into another? So if I have a triangle mesh can I turn or replace the mesh with a gLTF or another mesh?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add the HTTP URL to the GLTF loader and this is not allowed;
Try to convert to BLOB

in the new BLOB(Response.data) You can replace the response.data with the old URL

```
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
   this.loaders.gltfLoader.load(url , (file)=>{
       
   });
```

Here the loader will load perfectly without errors