# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): url.lastIndexOf is not a function in react-planner using threejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am currently using [react-planner](https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner) as a package in my react app. It comes with a list of 3d items using MTL, OBJ and texture files that are stored in a catalog, which is located in my SRC folder.

When I switch to 3d viewer it gives me an error when its trying to load the MTL and OBJ files.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function
```

And it points to my `loadObjWithMaterial` function found in the `load-obj.js` file.

```
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';

export function loadObjWithMaterial(mtlFile, objFile, imgPath) {
  let mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setResourcePath(imgPath);
  let url = mtlFile;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    mtlLoader.load(url, materials => {
      materials.preload();
      let objLoader = new OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.load(objFile, object => resolve(object));

    });
  });
}
```

This is how the planner presents the data and loads the function:

```
let mtl = require('./door.mtl');
let obj = require('./door.obj');
let img = require('./texture.jpg');

return loadObjWithMaterial(mtl, obj, img)
  .then(object => {
    cached3DDoor = object;
    return onLoadItem(cached3DDoor.clone())
  })
```

When I do `console.log(url)`, I get this in the console:

```
Object { default: "/static/media/door.3052bdbf.mtl", … }
```

When I open that link I am able to view the file, what am I missing?

I checked another question where they stated that its to do with the URL not being a string, but when I applied that in the following format I still got an error.

Following this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530051/how-do-i-fix-the-three-js-url-lastindexof-is-not-a-function-error)

I swapped my

```
let url = mtlFile;
```

with

```
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([mtlFile]));
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!DOCTYPE html>"
```

I'd appreciate any pointers or suggestions at this point, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of another developer it became very obvious was missing. `loadObjWithMaterial` wants the link to the object, but for some reason I was providing it with an `object` that contained the link on `default` but not the direct link.

Thus I had to modify the code of `load-obj.js` to the following:

```
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';

export function loadObjWithMaterial(mtlFile, objFile, imgPath) {
  let mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setResourcePath(imgPath.default);
  let url = mtlFile.default;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    mtlLoader.load(url, materials => {
      materials.preload();
      let objLoader = new OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.load(objFile.default, object => resolve(object));

    });
  });
}
```

I am not sure why the webpack was able to provide the links immediately, but for some reason running the app as a module in a react app (17 is what I am using) meant that the links would need to be accessed individually as they were provided inside an object.

I'd love to understand why, if anyone has the answer to that, I couldn't find anything out about this.

Edit:
I have found out that `require();` gets the object's url if its ran in webpack directly with babel, however in React this functionality behaves differently.

In react it gets the URL and puts it inside an object, which is why when you try to read the url, you will have to call it specifically through the default.

My solution was to replace all the `require()` parts with `import`.

```
import mtl from "/door.mtl";
import obj from "./door.obj";
import img from "./texture.jpg";

return loadObjWithMaterial(mtl, obj, img)
  .then(object => {
    cached3DDoor = object;
    return onLoadItem(cached3DDoor.clone())
  })
```